# Converting 15 min data to daily average and joining with daily table? - SQL

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, inner-join, average

I'm working on a project and am trying to mesh together daily data (proddate / OIL / Gas / Water) and 15min data (logtime / field name / datavalue)

Pulling this data for 2 years back seems to break my python script (crashes the kernel). I'm trying to parse it down in SQL on the front end.

What I'm looking for is converting the 15min data (logtime) to an average daily number. The data being averaged would be (datavalue). Ideally this would leave me with a "proddate" and "logtime" that are both daily and a "datavalue" that is the average for the day.

```
 SELECT w.XID, w.wellname, Fieldname, logtime, datavalue, proddate, OilProd_BBL as OIL, GasProd_MCF as Gas, WaterProd_BBL as Water
 FROM X_DW.elx.DeviceReadings r
 INNER JOIN X_VIEWS.dbo.Wells w
     ON r.DeviceId = w.ScadaID
 INNER JOIN [X_VIEWS].[dbo].[Production] p
     ON w.XID = p.XID
 WHERE logtime > GETDATE() - 5
     AND w.XID = 'QW081588'
     AND FieldName IN ('DischargePress_PSI', 'IntakePress_PSI','MotorTemp_F','Power_Amps','Frequency_HZ')
```

To get this to run I've been using:

```
 WHERE logtime > GETDATE() - 5
```

to reduce the amount of rows... but like I said above I'd like to go back a couple of years.

I'm guessing there needs to be an "avg" somewhere in select with a group by somewhere.... the multiple inner joins with groupby is throwing me off I think.

Here is what the output logtime looks like:

```
2022-08-18 19:00:01.000
```

What this query returns right now

```
XID         Wellname     Fieldname    Logtime                     Datavalue  proddate    OIL    GAS   WATER
QW081588    superwell    Power_Amps   2022-08-18 19:00:01.000     50         8-18-22     100    200   300
QW081588    superwell    Power_Amps   2022-08-18 19:15:01.000     45         8-18-22     100    200   300
QW081588    superwell    Power_Amps   2022-08-18 19:30:01.000     60         8-18-22     100    200   300
QW081588    superwell    Power_Amps   2022-08-18 19:45:01.000     55         8-18-22     100    200   300
QW081588    superwell    MotorTemp_F  2022-08-18 19:00:01.000     300        8-18-22     100    200   300
QW081588    superwell    MotorTemp_F  2022-08-18 19:15:01.000     290        8-18-22     100    200   300
QW081588    superwell    MotorTemp_F  2022-08-18 19:30:01.000     250        8-18-22     100    200   300
QW081588    superwell    MotorTemp_F  2022-08-18 19:45:01.000     301        8-18-22     100    200   300
```

This is what I'd want it to return:

```
XID         Wellname     Fieldname    Logtime                  avg(Datavalue)  proddate    OIL    GAS   WATER
QW081588    superwell    Power_Amps   8-18-22                     52.5         8-18-22     100    200   300
QW081588    superwell    MotorTemp_F  8-18-22                     285.3        8-18-22     100    200   300
```

The frustrating part about this... is that I handled all the meshing and averaging in python... but when trying to go back very far it kills the kernel "The Kernel crashed while executing code"

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the query that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving this yourself, and then explain what result you're getting versus what result you expect.

Comment: Sorry it took me a min... Let me know if that's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Select clause, in place of logtime, use `convert(date,logtime)`.

At the end of the query, add the line

```
group by w.XID, w.wellname, Fieldname, convert(date,logtime), proddate, OilProd_BBL, GasProd_MCF, WaterProd_BBL
```

And finally, in the Select clause in place of Datavalue, use `avg(Datavalue)`

I'm not sure how the Oil/water/gas figures in to all this, so you may have to make further adjustments if they're not all 100/200/300 all the time.

Comment: Thanks man, that greatly reduced the amount of rows I'm pulling! Cheers sir.